# JavaScript regex - How to wrap matches with tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in JavaScript in which I'd like to find all matches of a given phrase and wrap them with a tag. I haven't been able to find the right regex method here to replace a case insensitive phrase and replace it with itself with additional text around it. For example:

**Input string:**

```
"I like to play with cats, as does Cathy, who is a member of ACATA, which is the American Cat And Tiger Association."
```

Case insensitive phrase:  "cat"

**Output string:**

```
"I like to play with <em>cat</em>s, as does <em>Cat</em>hy, who is a member of A<em>CAT</em>A, which is the American <em>Cat</em> And Tiger Association."
```

So, basically, inject `<em></em>` around any matches. I can't just do a straight-up replace, because I'll lose the original case in the input string.

Answer (score 17):

You could use:

```
"Foo bar cat".replace(/(cat)/ig, "<em>$1</em>");
```

Which will return:

```
"Foo bar <em>cat</em>"
```

Comment: Perfect, after having spent 15 minutes reading other posts I have finally found exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You can do straight-up replace by using a [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
str.replace(/cat/ig, function replace(match) { 
    return '<em>' + match + '</em>'; 
});
```

Comment: You can leverage `<em>$1</em>` as the replacement string instead of having a function.

Answer (score 5):

One needs no capturing group around the whole regex because there is a `$&` placeholder that refers to the whole match from the string replacement pattern:

```
"Foo bar cat".replace(/cat/ig, "<em>$&</em>");
                                    ^^
```

See the [Specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) section:

> `$&`    Inserts the matched substring.

Thus, no need of any callback methods or redundant regex constructs.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it very simple, just use a `capturing group` with the `word` you want, and then use the replacement string `<em>$1</em>`. You can use a regex like this:

```
(cat)
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN8vK3/2)**

Below, you can see in green the matches (capturing the word `cat` insensitively) and in the `substitution section` you can see the replacements.

[image]

You can use this code:

```
var re = /(cat)/ig; 
var str = '"I like to play with cats, as does Cathy, who is a member of ACATA, which is the American Cat And Tiger Association."\n';
var subst = '<em>$1</em>'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```