# Is it possible to set a background color on individual words using just CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this effect:

```css
h1 span {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>This</span>
    <span>is</span>
    <span>Life</span>
</h1>
```

However, the project I'm working is meant to be used on a CMS, and I cannot expect my client to know how to add span tags (especially since it will require using a class on the actual site). So I'm wondering whether it is possible to recreate this effect without breaking each word into a separate element. I already know this is possible via JavaScript, and am looking specifically for CSS-only solutions.

Comment: Pretty sure that's impossible with CSS only.

Comment: if you can't use JS at all then consider to output the sentence from your server in this format and just add your CSS class

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you might want to consider is [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), if you want to style the words in a particular order.  But if you're looking to style based on the words themselves, no, you can't do that with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do that for you, and add the file to your costumer's website.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};


var str = $("h1").html();
var re = /[^\s]/;
var subst = '<span>$&</span>'; 

var result = str.replaceAll(re, subst);

$("h1").html(result);
```

```css
h1 span {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>hello there !.</h1>
```

ref:

[adding tag by regular expression  replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616950/3091563)

[replace all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/3091563)